# See which view contains the form that posted to a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a contoller action that a number of forms will post to, all in different views.
Is there a way, in my controller action, to see which view contained the form that posted to it?

I need this to determine to where to redirect the action when the code in the post action is complete.
Thank you!

Comment: is the "view" you're referring to a class yoou've written, which inherits from a class within your asp mvc framework, and with a corresponding markup file containing the actual html form element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options...you can add a field to your form (or query string) that provides the redirect url. Or you can look at the [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) field. It will provide you with the full URL which you have to parse to get the original form.

Hope this helps

Comment: It does thank you! I will probably just use the first option with a field.